# Work by Gravity using Tensors

Tags: gravity, work, tensor-calculus

Now I'm familiar with the various methods for deriving work done by gravity, but I noticed a few things about the situation, and wanted to see if I could properly apply a tensor treatment to the situation. I get the correct answer from the derivation, but knowing the proper outcome I feel could impeded my logic. I'm wanting to know if the following mathematics is proper:

Starting with the assumption that gravity is a conservative force, we then know that $ F^i = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_i} $, where the $ x^i$ are some generalized coordinates, and $ \psi (x^i)$ some scalar *potential* function of those generalized coordinates. So generally speaking, let's say we have some arbitrary coordinate system characterized by $ g_{ij} $ to be defined explicitly later for calculation, and some force, $F^i$, to be applied over some path $C$ in differential elements $dx^i$.

Now before even setting up the integral for work, my first question is what type of first order tensor should I use to define the force and the differential displacement? Intuition leads me to believe that I need only define them as either both contravariant or covariant, and use the metric tensor to raise/lower and index on the force or displacement in order to have a covariant tensor expression for the scalar work. In other words, is it true that my only options for the work dot product are:

$$ g_{ij}F^{i}dx^{j} \bigwedge g^{ij}F_{i}dx_{j} $$

Assuming this to be true, we then have for the work:

$$ W = \oint g_{ij}F^{i}dx^{j} $$

but since gravity is conservative, $F^{i} = \partial^{i}\psi $

Pushing the metric tensor through for beauty's sake and applying the Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals:

$$ \oint g_{ij}F^{i}dx^{j} = \oint F^{i}dx_{i} = \oint \partial^{i}\psi dx_i = \psi(x^{i}_{(f)}) - \psi(x^{i}_{(i)}) $$

In this case, $\psi(x^{i})$ corresponds to gravitational potential.

Choosing spherical coordinates in 3D:

$$ x^{i} : i \in \{1,2,3\} \, \wedge \, x^1 = r, x^2 = \theta, x^3 = \phi $$

$$ g_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & r^2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & r^2sin^2\theta \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ F^i : F^1 = -\frac{GMm}{r^2}, F^2=F^3=0 $$

In other words, gravity has no $\theta$ or $\phi$ component, and thus acts purely radially. The fact that the other two coordinates are cyclic indicates spherical symmetry which reinforces intuition.

This then means we only need to work with $i=1$: the radial component. Pressing on (ignoring the metric contraction since $g_{rr}=1$):

$$ F^r = -\frac{GMm}{r^2} = \partial^r \psi $$
$$ W = \int_{r_i}^{r_f}\partial^r \psi dr = \int_{r_i}^{r_f} -\frac{GMm}{r^2} dr  $$

$$ = GMm(\frac{1}{r_f} - \frac{1}{r_i}) $$

Which is indeed the desired result. The question, again, is then: Is my mathematics consistent? If this is more of a mathematics stack question, please let me know, and I'll move it.

Comment: This seems to be a check-my-work question, which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: It's the rationale of the mathematics I'm most concerned about. I know the work is correct.

Comment: @Danu, if this is truly off topic, what could be done to make it not seem so? I feel like I'm being cheated out of the degree of insight I'm seeking.